# Which tense should I use after "by the time you read this"?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

Could you please advise which sentence is grammatically correct?

> By the time you read this, **I have** already bought tickets and **I have**
>   reserved a hotel.

or

> By the time you read this, **I have** already bought tickets and **reserved**
>   a hotel.

or

> By the time you read this, **I had** already bought tickets and **reserved** a
>   hotel.

or

> By the time **you are reading** this, I.....

or

Any better way to structure the same sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the (rather rare) cases when we actually use the future perfect in everyday English.

> By the time you read this, I will already have bought tickets and reserved a hotel.

(The "will have" could be repeated, but normally would not be).

In speech, most people would say "I'll" rather than "I will". In a written note, they might use either.